# Correct way to deny a user action in django?

Tags: python, django

I'm developing an e-commerce. Currently, i want to prevent the user from having access to Product DetailView of expired products. I can do this using UserPassesTestMixin, but as I'm not testing any userType, i don't know if it's the best way.

models.py

```
class ProdutosDetail(UserPassesTestMixin, DetailView):
    model = Produto
    template_name = "produto/produto_detail.html"
    context_object_name = "product"


    def test_func(self):
        try:
            assert self.get_object().expiration_date > date.today()
        except AssertionError:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

Answer (score 0):

If the result situation is user unrelated you can omit these in the queryset itself? (resulting in 404s). If there's still 'special' users that *should* be able to view the objects, you could override 'get_queryset' or use some sort of mixin like you've already suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The user does not need to pass a test, the object, you thus can filter with:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Now


class ProdutosDetail(DetailView):
    model = Produto
    queryset = Producto.objects.filter(expiration_date__gt=Now())
    template_name = 'produto/produto_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'product'
```

Comment: THK, this work. I think I did the hardest.